# Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (default)

Tags: java, spring, maven, openmrs

I am trying to package my mavenized project, but it always bring up an error. I have tried various things to resolve it,still yet, the problem remains the same.

This is the error I usually get when trying to package my project:

> ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:exec-maven-plugin:1.4.0:exec (default) on project mymodule-omod: Command execution failed. Cannot run program "bower" (in directory "C:\Users\osagie\Documents\GitHub\mymodule\omod\src\main\webapp\resources\scripts"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid -> [Help 1]

Attached is the project structure:

[image]

Comment: The problem is this: `Command execution failed. Cannot run program "bower" (in directory "C:\Users\osagie\Documents\GitHub\mymodule\omod\src\main\webapp\resources\scripts"): CreateProcess error=267, The directory name is invalid` You should set the working directory in exec-maven-plugin...

Comment: @khmarbaise I have already done that